# What does ガッコンガッコンと mean in this sentence?

Tags: onomatopoeia

The sentence is describing a giant robot, with its giant drill stored in its chest started to rotating, thrusting in and out violently (?)

But I don't understand what does this sfx means here, please help me to understand its meaning. Much thanks o/

> 胸部に格納してあった巨大ドリルを回転させながら、**ガッコンガッコンと**前後に激しくピストン運動させる。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic form of this onomatopoeia is ガコン. Many people would say exactly that it's the metallic noise a giant robot makes when it walks or moves its joints. Others may say it's the noise of a half-broken washing machine, or the trunk of an old car being closed violently.

You can hear many audio clips tagged with ガコン here: https://pixta.jp/audio/tags/%E3%82%AC%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3

[ガタン](https://pixta.jp/audio/tags/%E3%82%AC%E3%82%BF%E3%83%B3) refers to almost the same type of sound, but for some reason I feel ガコン is more commonly associated with giant robots.